# Parsing large sized countries' osm files in matlab

Tags: xml, matlab, openstreetmap

How can I parse a country osm file of xml format in matlab knowing that the file size can reach up to 30 GB and the maximum Java heap memory needed for the parsing code (parse_openstreetmap) from matlab central is only about 4.093 GB? and Is it possible to make use of the pbf format to extract unneeded information before parsing on matlab? Thanks in advance

Comment: As far as I know, 30GB is really too much for MATLAB to handle, at least with its native functions. However, you can try rolling your own MEX file to parse such files and return data of reasonable size that MATLAB can cope with.

Comment: Is it really necessary to parse the raw OSM file? Otherwise you can pre-filter the file using [osmfilter](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmfilter) / [osmconvert](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Osmconvert) or retrieve only specific data using the [Overpass API](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Overpass_API).

Answer (score 0):

Normally you can use `xlmread` to read xlm files in matlab.

Of course you can try that, but if it turns out the file is too big it may be possible to [read it line by line](https://stackoverflow.com/a/2858208/983722) with lower level commands like `fgetl`

It would require some effort to actually extract the information that you need.

You may also want to try [splitting the xml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700213/xml-split-of-a-large-file), though the offered solutions do not mention the maximum size for xml files.