# How To Split Discogs Database Dump To Upload?

Tags: mysql, xml

### [Discogs Database Dump](http://www.discogs.com/data/)

Please see the bottom of this page for the latest dump. I am trying to upload the likes of the discogs_20150301_labels.xml however my server only allows a maximum file upload of 500MB (I'm using the 1and1 shared server on the advanced plus package).

How can I split this file to upload in chunks to continue work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Answer to following related Stackoverflow question lists several xml split utilities for you to research:

[XML Split of a Large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700213/xml-split-of-a-large-file/7823719#7823719)