# What is the limit of number of lines in a Visual Studio file (XML or cs)?

Tags: c#, xml, visual-studio, max

I have created an XML file in VS 2017 with 100,000+ lines and VS crashed every time I've tried to modify this file. (please don't tell me that my design is bad and I should use a database).
I have also created a unit test file with C# with more than 100,000 lines and VS 2017 also crashed every time I've tried to modify the file (.cs)
My pc is a Windows 10 with 24 GB of RAM so it is not a resource issue.
So my question is what is the max number of lines VS can handle correctly ?

Comment: [If you're asking for a limit you're probably doing something wrong](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20070301-00/?p=27803).

Comment: According to [this](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/87c23f8c-033d-4e1a-bf72-872b7000b60d/whats-the-maximum-size-of-c-source-file-that-vs-can-open?forum=vseditor) there was no hard limit in VS2010

Comment: Visual Studio is a 32-bit program. Therefore, it is limited in memory as a 32-bit process.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either you are trying to benchmark Visual Studio IDE for some research you are doing or you are in a real need to process large files.

If you are looking for benchmark I cannot help you.

If you are in a real need to process large files; I recommend you to split the file into smaller files as illustrated in the answer for this question:
[XML Split of a Large file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/700213/xml-split-of-a-large-file)